# turn static method of class into variable typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, service

Hi all so currently I am making a service for my application/library i am creating and so far this is the best way I can figure out how to create a service. Ideally I would like to change this method into a variable for easier reading

```html
import { NavigationRoute, NavigationParams } from 'react-navigation';
import { NavigationStackProp } from 'react-navigation-stack';

type Navigation =
  | NavigationStackProp<NavigationRoute<NavigationParams>, NavigationParams>
  | undefined;

export default class NavigationService {
  private static _navigator: Navigation;

  public static setNavigator(navigatorRef: Navigation) {
    this._navigator = navigatorRef;
  }

  public static navigate = (): Navigation => {
    // TODO: look into how to make this a variable
    return NavigationService._navigator;
  };
}
```

currently i have this

```html
      IconPress: () => NavigationService.navigate()?.openDrawer()
```

but would love for it to read like this

```html
      IconPress: () => NavigationService.navigate?.openDrawer()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is called a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get):

```
export default class NavigationService {

    public static get navigate(): Navigation {
        return NavigationService._navigator;
    } 
}
```

Comment: amazing thank you. wasn't sure how to write the correct syntax :)